# Access, Controls, #Name

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have an Access database with the following tables:

- Table1
- Table2

Each of these tables have these 2 fields

- Field1
- Field2

I have a form with 2 text box controls:
[image]

What I'm trying to do is to get the first text box to display "field 1 from table 1" and the second text box to get "Field 1 from table 2". Using the following expression as the control source will only return "field 1 from table 1":

```
Field1
```

Using the following expressions will result in the value "#Name?" to be displayed:

```
[Table2]![Field1] 
[Table2].[Field1] 
=[Table2]![Field1] 
=[Table2].[Field1]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ok just realized a table can only get data from one table only. In order to achieve this I would need to use queries to join the tables